# Docker postgres persistance and container lifetime

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker. You can take a look at my last questions here and see that I've been asking questions down this line. I read the docs carefully, and also read several articles on the web (which is pretty difficult given the rapid versioning in docker), but I still can't get a clear picture of how am I supposed to use containers and its impact on persistance.

The official postgres image creates a volume in its Dockerfile using this command

```
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

And the readme.md file shows only one example of how to run the image

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

When I try that, I can see (with "docker inspect some-postgres") that the volume created lives in a random directory in my host, and it seems to "belong" to that particular container.

So here are some questions that may help my understanding:

1. It looks (from the official postgres image docs) that expected usage is to use "docker run" to create the container, and "docker start" afterwards (this last bit I inferred from the fact that -d and --name are used). This makes sense to me, but conflicts with a lot of information I've seen regarding containers should be ephemeral. If spin a new container every time, then the default VOLUME config in the Dockerfile doesn't work for persistance. What's the right way of doing things?
2. Given the above is correct (that I can run once and start many times), the only reason I see for the VOLUME command in the Dockerfile is I/O performance because of the CoW filesystem bypass. Is this right?
3. Could you please clearly explain what's wrong with using this approach over the (I think unofficially) recommended way of using a data container? I'd like to know the pros/cons to my specific situation, which is a node js intranet application.

Thanks,
Awer

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you can start the container using 'docker run' and start it again in the future using 'docker start' assuming you haven't removed the container. You're also correct that docker containers are supposed to be ephemeral and you shouldn't be in bad shape if the container disappears. What you can do is mount a volume into the docker container to the storage location of the database.

```
docker run -v /postgres/storage:/container/postgres --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

If you know the location of where the database writes to inside the container you can mount it correctly and then even if you remove the postgres container, when you start back up all your data will persist. You may need to mount some other areas that control configurations as well unless you modify and save the container.